# Escape string in PowerShell Regex to a regular string

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a string that contains some regex in, `$(=?`, Now this string is a password that I need to pass for some application that I'm building.

The code that I'm trying to use is:

```
$x = 'GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7'
[Regex]::Escape($x)
```

I've already tried the method with `[Regex]::Escape()` and it doesn't meet my requirements because I'm trying to insert the string as a password and it replacing the Regex with `\`.

Perhaps after I'm doing the `[Regex]::Escape()` should I try to delete the `\` that I'm getting from the result of the command?

After running the `[Regex]::Escape()` this is the result I'm getting when printing the output:

```
GIWs@K\?hks2v&HKXb=HK\*AZN=i!\(S\?7
```

I'm trying to achieve the string without the ' \ ' characters but with the Escape function:

```
GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb=HK*AZN=i!(S?7
```

Comment: You don't show the failing command. Why not use the `.replace()` method which is ***not*** RegEx based?

Comment: I've edited the question with the failing output. What you mean by .replace() ? After running the [Regex]::Escape to put a .replace() on the variable?

Comment: there are [at least] TWO `replace` techniques in PoSh. `-replace` is a string operator that uses regex. `.Replace()` is a string method _and does not use regex at all_.

Comment: **_please_** post the CODE you are trying to run.

Comment: The problem here is that you have a string with `$S9` in it. PowerShell thinks that is a variable. Since it is not, it is replaced with a null value effectively erasing it from the string.

Comment: Thanks for the down votes i'll learn again the rules of asking a question, but for @AdminOfThings I do get that but I'm trying to get this ```$``` as a string and not regex

Comment: Use single quotes around string literals: `[regex]::escape('dfaseryh$S9=r4e3sdf')`. PowerShell will not attempt to interpolate `$`.

Comment: Still the same result, replacing to single quotes ```GIWs@K\?hks2v&HKXb\$S9=HK\*AZN=i!\(S\?7``` after running : ```GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7``` and please avoid long comments, publish an answer :)

Comment: We are without context to provide an answer. You say you want to use `[regex]::escape` but aren't happy with the escape characters provided by the method. Then don't use `Escape()`. `Escape()` without the escape characters is your original string. So just don't mess with it? The responders really need to see how this particular regex string is going to be used to better assist you.

Comment: I already done that, the code that I'm trying is this : ```$x = GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7 [Regex]::Escape($x)```

Comment: @DorShamay - that is not the point ... what are you trying to _replace_? what are you trying to use regex to replace? where is the code for that ... because there is NO problem with the code you have shown. ///// also, to replay to a person, you should use the `@UserName` tag at the start of your comment.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve that my string that includes a regex like =$(& would be processed as a regular string which means, all of the characters on the string will be in 1 single string and not divided because of a Powershell Regex.

Comment: As stated, to specify a literal (verbatim) string in PowerShell, enclose it in `'...'` (single quotes). You cannot use _unquoted_ strings in an _expression_ such as `$x = GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7` - that will simply _fail_.

Comment: @mklement0 I've added the enclose that I've done as well and still have the same problem.

Comment: *What* problem? Your code is telling PowerShell to escape special characters in a regular expression string (i.e. prepend them with a backslash). Why are you surprised that PowerShell is doing exactly what you told it to do? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer because I don't know what the problem actually is. However, there are some inherent problems with your current attempt to handle the password string. If you use double quotes (`""`) around a string, PowerShell will interpolate the string inside the quotes. So any alphanumeric characters following an unescaped `$`, will be considered a variable name during interpolation. If that variable has no value, `$variable` will be replaced with a null value. You can see this behavior below:

```
"rt4837s$GT=\"
rt4837s=\
```

You should use single quotes (`''`) when quoting string literals (characters that will be left as is). PowerShell will not attempt interpolation when unescaped single quote pairs are encountered unless there is quote nesting. See below:

```
'rt4837s$GT=\'
rt4837s$GT=\
```

If you need a regex escaped string, the same rules apply from above and you should use single quotes.

```
[regex]::escape('dfaseryh$S9=r??*')
dfaseryh\$S9=r\?\?\*
```

If for any reason, you need to access that string later without the escape characters, then you can use the regex method `Unescape()`.

```
[regex]::unescape('dfaseryh\$S9=r\?\?\*')
dfaseryh$S9=r??*
```

---

**Practical Example of Using Regex Replace:**

```
$OriginalString = 'Username = Anonymous; Password = <password>'
$regexReplace = [regex]::Escape('<password>')
$Password = 'GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7'

$OriginalString -replace $regexReplace,($Password -replace '\$','$$$$')
# Output 
Username = Anonymous; Password = GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7
```

In the code above, `$OriginalString` is just an ordinary string that can be retrieved from any command or set by a coder. It contains a string `<password>` that we want to replace with a complex password string `GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7`.

`$Password` contains the complex password. Since we only care about replacing `<password>` and are choosing to use regex replace operator `-replace`, we need a valid regex expression for matching `<password>`. There is a caveat here though. When using `-replace`, the `$` in the replacement string is used to prefix capture group names. So there can be cases where the literal string has an unintentional replacement. Capture group 0 is always there if there is a match. So `$0` will always cause issues without proper escaping. It is probably best to just escape `$` regardless.

For the regex match, we use `[regex]::Escape('<password>')` since we are unsure if `<>` are special in regex. If there are no special characters, then the string within the regex expression will not be modified. If it does contain special characters, they will be escaped with `\`.

As a result, `<password>` is replaced with `GIWs@K?hks2v&HKXb$S9=HK*AZN=i!(S?7`.

A recap of the syntax is as follows:

```
'String With Something You Want to Replace' -replace 'Regex Expression to Match String You Want to Replace','Replacement That Is a Literal String With Escaped $'
```

Comment: As you have wrote in here, after using the single quotes ' '  and afterwards using the [regex]::escape You still getting my result that irrelevant to the result I'm trying to achieve, full string that includes the regex without the \ before each Regex.

Comment: That is not how regex works. Special characters in a regex expression must be escaped if you want regex to treat them as literal strings. Maybe you are just confusing when you need to use regex. Here is an example of regex replace: `$OriginalString -replace $regexString,$NewString`. Of this example, only `$regexString` is a regex expression. The `$NewString` or the replacement string is just a string. If that's what you are trying to do, then you don't need regex for the replacement string.